# Finding $a$ and $b$ values in a polynomial function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 -x + 3$ is divided by $(x+1)$, the remainder is $3$. When $f(x)$ is divided by $(x+2)$, the remainder is $-7$.

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to math se. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You get more help here when you show your effort as part of your question.

Comment: What about [this thread?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941104/polynomials-and-division?rq=1)

Comment: **Possible duplicate**: (thanks to  @ΘΣΦGenSan) is given at the question[polynomials and division](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/44376/%ce%98%ce%a3%ce%a6gensan)

Answer (score 1):

We have $$f(x)=ax^3+bx^2-x+3$$

We can say, using the [Polynomial Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)$^{*}$, that

\begin{align}f(-1)&=3\\
f(-2)&=-7\end{align}

Therefore, we have

\begin{align}a(-1)^3+b(-1)^2-(-1)+3&=3\\
-a+b+1+3&=3\\
a-b&=1\\
\\
a(-2)^3+b(-2)^2-(-2)+3&=-7\\
-8a+4b+2+3&=-7\\
2a-b&=3\end{align}

We can solve these simultaneous equations:

\begin{align}a&=1+b\\
&\Downarrow\\
2(1+b)-b&=3\\
2+2b-b&=3\\
2+b&=3\\
b&=1\\
&\Downarrow\\
a&=1+1\\
a&=2\end{align}

Therefore, the asnwer is $a=2$, $b=1$ and thus $$f(x)=2x^3+x^2-x+3$$

---

$^*$ The [Polynomial Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) states that the remainder when a polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)$ is equal to $f(a)$ ie, we could say that $$f(x)=k(x-a)+f(a)$$

The proof can be seen by clicking on the link

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is a problem with division. Consider $23\div 7 = 3R2$ because $23 = 3\times 7 + 2$. We do something similar with polynomials. Consider the result of dividing $3x^2+2x+7$ by $x+2$.
We have
$$\begin{align}
3x^2+2x+7 &= 3x^2\color{red}{+6x-6x}+2x+7\\
&= 3x(x+2)-6x+2x+7\\
&= 3x(x+2)-4x+7\\
&= 3x(x+2)-4x\color{red}{-8+8}+7\\
&= 3x(x+2)-4(x+2)+8+7\\
&= 3x(x+2)-4(x+2)+15\\
&= (3x-4)(x+2)+15\\
\end{align}$$

Thus $(3x^2+2x+7)\div (x+2) = (3x-4) \text{ }R\text{ }15$

The above could also have been done in fractional form.
$$\frac{3x^2+2x+7}{x+2} = \frac{3x^2\color{red}{+6x-6x}+2x\color{red}{-8+8}+7}{x+2}=\dots$$

Just use this (or a similar method) to find the remainders in terms of $a$ and $b$ in the original problem.